# XMLUnit - How to compare a self-closing tag to one which isn't?

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xmlunit

I have two pieces of XML, a part of which is :

```
<userActionRequiredCode>0</userActionRequiredCode>

<userActionRequiredCode xsi:nil="1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

These are in different files which I am comparing using XMLUnit.

These are different as you can see, not same, not similar. What options can I set for **XMLUnit** or the **Diff** class or anywhere so that I can take this difference into consideration.

Currently this doesn't show up in the list of differences.

Edit : Updated sample.

**UPDATE** : The original problem wasn't with XMLUnit recognizing the difference. It was a mistake on my part. XMLUnit correctly recognizes the difference. This particular problem, hence is bogus, irreplicable.

Comment: Ehh, what? `<userActionRequiredSince>` and `<userActionRequiredCode>` are not even the same tag, so what are you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, updated to reflect correct sample.

Comment: A value of `0` and a value of nothing (empty string or `nil`) is not the same value. Are you saying that XMLUnit claim them to be equal?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't show up in the diff.

Comment: Unable to replicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) shows them to be different, so if you don't get a difference, then you setup XMLUnit to not do so.

```
final String control = "<userActionRequiredCode>0</userActionRequiredCode>";
final String test = "<userActionRequiredCode xsi:nil=\"1\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"/>";

Diff myDiff = DiffBuilder.compare(Input.fromString(control))
                         .withTest(Input.fromString(test))
                         .build();
System.out.println(myDiff.toString());
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Expected child nodelist length '1' but was '0' - comparing <userActionRequiredCode...> at /userActionRequiredCode[1] to <userActionRequiredCode...> at /userActionRequiredCode[1]
```